# Solve for exponents

Tags: equation-solving

I have this problem that I"m trying to work out:
[image]

Here's my attemp:

```
me = 0.51109991
mp = 938.2723
mpe = mp/me
Solve[(2^n)*(3^mm)*(\[Pi]^p) == mpe, {n, mm, p}]
```

However *Mathematica* told me to use Reduce because there were calculations involving inverse functions and so I did. However I got this error message:

```
Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
```

I'm just wondering what did I do wrong and how would I solve this problem properly?

Comment: BTW: `UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "ProtonElectronMassRatio"]]` gives the ratio directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or

```
Minimize[{Abs[(2^n)*(3^mm)*(\[Pi]^p) - mpe], 
  n > 0 && mm > 0 && p > 0}, {n, mm, p}, Integers]
```

> `{0.327725, {n -> 1, mm -> 1, p -> 5}}`

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, you can also visually solve it.

```
me = 0.51109991;
mp = 938.2723;
mpe = mp/me;
eq[n_, m_, p_] = 2^n*3^m*Pi^p;

Manipulate[
 Plot[{mpe, eq[n, m, p]}, {n, 0, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic], {m, 0, 2}, {p, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
{mpe, eq[1, 1, 5]} // N
{1835.79, 1836.12}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try all the integers less than 10 - it takes a fraction of a second,

```
me = 0.51109991;
mp = 938.2723;
data = Table[{Abs[(2^n)*(3^mm)*(π^p) - mp/me], {n, mm, p}}, {n, 0,
      10}, {mm, 0, 10}, {p, 0, 10}]~Flatten~2;
```

Now find the point with the smallest difference,

```
data[[First@Ordering@data]]
(* {0.327725, {1, 1, 5}} *)
```

and then check your result

```
mp/me
N@(2^1) 3^1 π^5
(* 1835.79 *)
(* 1836.12 *)
```

To four significant digits they are both 1836!

Comment: You can also find the point with `MinimalBy[data, Position]`

Comment: @rewi what do you think it does? The result it gives is only accidentaly correct.

Comment: @Kuba MinimalBy sorts the data for which the first element in the data packet is minimal {{0.327725,{1,1,5}}}. It's no matter whether one gives it in the form `MinimalBy[data, First]` or `MinimalBy[data,_]`. With `MinimalBy[data,Last]` MinimalBy sorts the data for which the last element in the data packet is minimal {{1834.79,{0,0,0}}}. The code snippet `data[[First@Ordering@data]]` can be replaced by `MinimalBy[data, First]`. The obtained result is not accidentaly or by chance.

Comment: @rewi it is, First or Last makes sense but `Position` or `"X"` doesn't, it just add the head, which won't affect the order since it is the same, Sort in MMA works that way that now it will sort accordint to the first argument, that's why all your examples return "correct" one.

Comment: @Kuba You're right. After I entered `MinimalBy[data,Position]`, as I said, in hindsight I was unsure and placed anything in the second position and got every time the same result. That surprised me and I was confused.

Answer (score 2):

This tries reasonable combinations of `i`, `m` and `p` and calculates the significant figures in base 10:

```
me = 51109991/100000000;
mp = 9382723/10000;
mpe = mp/me;

SortBy[Flatten[Table[{i, m, p, N[Log10[mpe/Abs[2^i 3^m \[Pi]^p - mpe]], 2]},
   {i, Log2[mpe]}, {m, Log[3, 2^-i mpe]}, {p, Floor[Log[\[Pi], 2^-i 3^-m mpe]],
    Ceiling[Log[\[Pi], 2^-i 3^-m mpe]]}], 2], Minus@*Last]
```

Of course I choose all variables to be at least 1, and I choose `i` to be at most `Log2[mpe]` because otherwise the result will be too large. Similarly for `m`, but for `p`, there is one equation with one unknown, which I solve and round down and up, respectively.

In general its a good idea to define your symbols with fractions and precede in arbitrary precision until efficiency becomes crucial, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

There's always lattice reduction for problems like this. I'll just show the code since the method really goes outside the scope of the intended problem.

```
me = 0.51109991;
mp = 938.2723;
mpe = mp/me;
vals = Log[{2, 3, Pi, mpe}];
lat = Transpose[
   Append[IdentityMatrix[4], Rationalize[N[10^4*vals], 0]]];
lat[[4, 4]] *= 10^2;
redlat = LatticeReduce[lat];
-redlat[[-1, 1 ;; 3]]

(* Out[1560]= {1, 1, 5} *)
```

The nice feature is that this becomes a linear problem in the sense that lattice reduction uses linear algebra under the hood.

Comment: Nice work for this!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
me = 51109991/100000000
mp = 9382723/10000
mpe = mp/me
Reduce[(2^n)*(3^mm)*(\[Pi]^p) == mpe, {n, mm, p}]

Element[C[1], Integers] && p == ((2*I)*Pi*C[1] + Log[(5864201875*2^(4 - n))/(51109991*3^mm)])/Log[Pi]
```